# React Router doesn't render components after build to ftp server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I built react app with `yarn build`.
To get the app running On my server, I added `"homepage": "./"` to the package.json file.
The app is stored in a folder on the server, and I access the app with https://my-url.com/appname

The App.js get's rendered, but I don't see my components:

```
function App() {
  const [navigationState, setNavigationState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header
          showNavigation={navigationState}
          setShowNavigation={setNavigationState}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
      <div className="space"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the `Header` component I have my links like

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Link to ="/contact">Contact</Link>
```

When I click on `Home` the URL switches to https://my-url.com/ and I see the Home component.
After clicking on `Contact` the URL switches to https://my-url.com/contact and I see the contact.

My .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

What do I need to do, to keep the folder path and render the home component on the first call?

- https://my-url.com/ `404`
- https://my-url.com/appname shows App Component but doesn't render the Home component
- https://my-url.com/appname/contact `404`
- https://my-url.com/contact `404`

After clicking on the Home link I get
-https://my-url.com/ showing the home component
After that clicking the Contact link, I get
https://my-url.com/contact showing the contact component

Reloading the page on both urls gives `404`.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER=firefox PORT=2000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

Comment: do you get a `404` when navigate to `https://my-url.com/contact`?

Comment: yes I do - I get a `404`

Comment: So, you said you can access your app at https://my-url.com/appname, right? so, would https://my-url.com/appname/contact work?

Comment: No, I get 404 as well. https://my-url.com/contact is the URL after clicking on the Home link once. It displays the component. But going directly to that URL doesn't work

Comment: I updated the URLs to be more specific.

Comment: Have you tried to deliver the app via express to test if the webserver is the problem?

Comment: I don't know what "deliver via express" is, but it is not working on my local machine and or my ftp server.

Comment: Please attach your package JSON .

Comment: I edited my question and added it

Comment: Can you try this: 

On your Router (e.g., `BrowserRouter` - I can only assume this is aliased as `Router` in your code), try to add a `basename`: e.g., `<Router basename="/appname">...</Router>` ...

After you've done that, replace your `.htaccess` with the following `.htaccess` and put it inside `/appname` folder: 

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.html?path=$1 [L,QSA]`

... lastly, on your `package.json`, use `.` instead of `./`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it working, I did the following steps:

- Add `.htaccess` file to `public` folder:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

- Modify the `package.json` and add:

```
"homepage": "http://my-url.com/foldername"
```

- In the `App.js` add the folder name to the `<Route path="<<here>>" />`:

```
<Route path="/foldername/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/foldername/contact" exact component={Contact} />
```

Comment: Hi @T.Karter what do you mean by folder name here? the location where the particular component present or something else?

Comment: To save from needing to prepend the directory name to every route path you can just specify a [basename](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) prop on the router to match where you've "deployed" the app on the server.

Comment: Nice solution! But you have to remember to put this .htaccess file inside your build folder

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem in previous project because it was GoDaddy Linux host with apache so I added this line

> "homepage": "my-url.com"
> to your package.json

then I edited my .htaccess file added my main rout on it

the file I used has this content

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . / [L]
```

Comment: Adding `"homepage": "my-url.com"` doesn't work at all. Adding `"homepage": "my-url.com/appname/"` works exactly the same as `./`. Maybe editing the `.htaccess` is the trick. What did you do there?

Comment: this is the file I used

`RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . / [L]
`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to the way the react-router is handling rendering either by the client or server-side rendering (SSR).
Please check this docs fragment to set it up correctly for client-side
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

or Try to change the config of rendering to SSR and it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem! I solved it to switch from `BrowserRouter` to `HashRouter` in my `App.jsx`. My FTP doesn't handle `BrowserRouter`.

After I updated everything it works fine.